# Push_back() doesn't work with Arduino-compatible Vector library (c++)

Tags: c++, vector, arduino, push-back

I'm trying to convert a char (containing only 0/1)  into a vector where each single char is stored as an integer.
He use Vector library for Arduino, which is not as well documented as basic c++ STL.
here is the function :

```
void reception_emission(char* message) {
    Vector <int> integers;
    Serial.println(message);
    Serial.println("suite");
    // Convertir la chaîne de caractères en un vecteur d'entiers
    for (int i = 0; i<strlen(message); ++i) {
        
        if (message[i] == '0' || message[i] == '1') {
            //integers.push_back(message[i] - '0')
             Serial.println(message[i]); 
              Serial.println("!!"); 
              const int nb=message[i] - '0';
              Serial.println(nb);
              Serial.println("////");
              
              integers.push_back(nb);
            } // Convertir le caractère en entier
        }
    
    Serial.print("size: "); 
    Serial.println(integers.size()); 
    // Appeler la fonction emission pour chaque entier dans le vecteur
    for (int i = 0; i < integers.size(); ++i) {
        //Serial.println(char(integers[i]));
        emission(laserPin, micros(), integers[i]);
        void_blank(laserPin, micros());
    }
}
```

I call it using :

```
reception_emission("01001010101");
```

I print many outputs to see what is exactly the problem.
On the serial monitor, I have :

```
0
!!
0
////
0
!!
0
////
1
!!
1
////
0
!!
0
////
1
!!
1
////
0
!!
0
////
1
!!
1
////
0
!!
0
////
1
!!
1
////
size: 0
```

it means that : every char is well converted in integer and stored in "nb".

But, at the end, you can see that the vector *interger* is still empty.

So, what is the problem here ?
did not find anything yet.

thank you.

Comment: Pet Peeve: Don't use `strlen` in a loop exit condition. Compilers are smart and getting smarter, but you can't always count on it being smart enough to not recompute the length of the string on every freakin' iteration. Instead use a pointer to a `char` and increment it until it points to a null. `for (char *chp = message; *chp != '\0'; chp++)` and the n you replace all of the `message[i]`s with `*chp`.

Comment: `Vector <int> integers;` provides no backing storage. Not sure what happens without storage, but it looks like it just discarded all of your inputs. Looking for good documentation.

Comment: [Had to go look at the code](https://github.com/janelia-arduino/Vector/blob/master/src/Vector/VectorDefinitions.h): `if ((values_ != NULL) && (size_ < max_size_))`. No backing store or too full, input silently discarded. Not a huge fan of that interface.

Comment: *Push_back() doesn't work* -- Why do you need all of this code to test what `Vector` does?  All you need is `Vector <int> integers; integers.push_back(1);  integers.push_back(2);` and see if `1` and `2` are stored in the vector.  It isn't important that you are trying to convert `'0'` and `'1'` to integers -- if the issue is `Vector`, a [mcve] just showing the operations you are having issues with is all that is necessary.

Comment: It's important to note that `Vector` does not automatically resize its backing store. This is common on an embedded device with a less complicated memory manager, as `vector` and similar structures that allocate, release and reallocate dynamic stores frequently quickly [fragment the device's memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_(computing)).

Answer (score 1):

Unlike `std::vector`, `Vector` does not provide its own memory storage.  You have to give it storage yourself.

According to the readme at https://github.com/janelia-arduino/Vector/tree/master:

> A sequence container similar to the C++ `std::vector`, **but instead of allocating memory dynamically, this container points to an external, statically allocated c style array.** The maximum size is fixed at compile time, but the size can change by pushing and popping elements from the vector. Static memory allocation is used to avoid dynamic allocation problems on very small embedded processors. Care must be taken not to dereference an empty vector, access elements beyond bounds, **or use without setting the storage array**.

As such, your `integers` vector is always empty because it has nothing to store its values into.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
void reception_emission(char* message) {

    const int ELEMENT_COUNT_MAX = ...; // whatever max size is reasonable for your neeeds...
    int storage_array[ELEMENT_COUNT_MAX];
    Vector <int> integers(storage_array);

    int msglen = strlen(message);
    for (int i = 0; i < msglen; ++i) {
        if (message[i] == '0' || message[i] == '1') {
            Serial.println(message[i]); 
            Serial.println("!!"); 
            const int nb = message[i] - '0';
            Serial.println(nb);
            Serial.println("////");
              
            integers.push_back(nb);
        }
    }
    
    Serial.print("size: "); 
    Serial.println(integers.size()); 

    for (int i = 0; i < integers.size(); ++i) {
        //Serial.println(char(integers[i]));
        emission(laserPin, micros(), integers[i]);
        void_blank(laserPin, micros());
    }
}
```

That being said, if you don't mind tweaking your logging a little then you can just get rid of the `Vector` altogether as you don't actually need it in this code:

```
void reception_emission(char* message) {

    Serial.println(message);
    Serial.println("suite");

    int msglen = strlen(message);
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < msglen; ++i) {        
        if (message[i] == '0' || message[i] == '1') {
            Serial.println(message[i]); 
            Serial.println("!!"); 
            const int nb = message[i] - '0';
            Serial.println(nb);
            Serial.println("////");
              
            //Serial.println(char(nb));
            emission(laserPin, micros(), nb);
            void_blank(laserPin, micros());

            ++count;
        }
    }
    
    Serial.print("count: "); 
    Serial.println(count);
}
```